# Change custom post type permalink according to category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, permalinks

Actual: `http://localhost/wp/subtitle/title-shahbaz/`

Post type: subtitle
Category of this post: internal
Want to show everywhere and also in URL bar:http://localhost/wp/internal-subtitle/title-shahbaz/

[Screenshot of the Admin panel](http://prntscr.com/ing7ei)

[Screenshot of the site](http://prntscr.com/ing7z7)

```
add_action( 'init', 'subtitle_post_type' );

function subtitle_post_type()
{

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => 'Subtitles',
    // more labels goes here
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => 'subtitle',
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array('comments'),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => false,
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'capability_type'       => 'page',
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' )
);
register_post_type( 'subtitle', $args );
}

 $labels = array(
    'name'             => __('Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    // more labels goes here
);

$args = array(
 'hierarchical'      => true,
 'labels'            => $labels,
 'show_ui'           => true,
 'show_admin_column' => true,
 'query_var'         => true,
 'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'type' ),
 );

 register_taxonomy( 'type', array( 'subtitle' ), $args );
```

This code I trying working correct for wp-admin but not for front side

```
function append_query_string( $url, $post ,$leavename, $sample ) {
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'type' );
$post_type= $post->post_type;

if( $terms[0]->name == 'internal'  && 'subtitle' ==  $post_type ) {
    return get_site_url( null, "/{$terms[0]->name}-{$post_type}/{$post->post_name}/" );
}
//}
return $url;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 11, 4 );
```

Comment: Does it need to be `/cpt-category/title` or could you use `/cpt/category/title`?

Comment: I need `/category-cpt/title`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your rewrite to add the course query var:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'course/%course%')
```

Then filter post_type_link to insert the selected course into the permalink:

```
function wpa_course_post_link( $post_link, $id = 0 ){
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if ( is_object( $post ) ){
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'course' );
        if( $terms ){
            return str_replace( '%course%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpa_course_post_link', 1, 3 );
```

There are also plugins like Custom Post Type Permalinks that can do this for you.

Comment: Its good but this applies to all category of this post I want to customize only one not all.